# fine settimana; masculine or feminine

Tags: word-usage

I am japanese "retraite", learning european languages on Japanese radio program.My question is about . These are the examples that confuse me. Radio program: <Senti, questo fine settimana che cosa fai?> Reservo online:<Questo fine settimana c'è la sua prima comunione.> and <Questa settimana mi è successo qualcosa che mi ha cambiato completamente.> Please explain,thank you. Hiro MIYAZAKI
p.s. I remember receiving an answer from Charo once.